# Wallet does not correspond to `.keys`

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, linux, keys-file

I changed the password of my wallet, upon realizing that that destroyed my seed phrase, I decided to try to change it back to see if the seed phrase would come back. Now I'm locked out of my wallet with the following error:

```
Error: failed to load wallet: file MyWallet does not correspond to MyWallet.keys
```

Comment: How did changing the password destroy the seed you wrote down on paper?  Make a new wallet and import the seed, re-sync wallet, enjoy responsibly.

Comment: @Dave okay well luckily I did write it down, but it was just dumb luck because I changed the password right afterwards. I could have easily done it in the other order, and what would I do then?

Comment: So did making a new wallet and restoring the seed work?  It should. (--restore-deteministic I think is the flag or something close to that)